# Wordpress Custom Post Meta Query

Tags: wordpress, meta

I'm trying query a custom post type for each comment with the dynamic field "comment_ID." I'm using the code below. This currently shows the comment ID, which I don't want, but does not show 'paid' as I would like.

```
<?php 
$commID = comment_ID();
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'paidbriefs', 'meta_key' => 'Comment_ID', 'meta_value' => 'echo $commID', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo 'paid';
endwhile; ?>
</p>
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong with echoing the `$commID` variable as this does not show anything. If I change this to just `$commID` it returns 'paid' for every comment that has a Comment_ID meta, regardless of whether it matches the actual comment ID. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you will need to do is a Loop, within a loop,

first loop to generate the standard loop, this will have your post info, comments etc. 
within that loop you need to declare your comment_ID;

then from there, you setup another internal loop, 
using the comment_ID for your custom field,

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'paidbriefs', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
   $commID = comment_ID();
   $innerargs = array( 'post_type' => 'paidbriefs', 
                       'meta_key' => 'Comment_ID', 
                       'meta_value' => $commID, 
                       'posts_per_page' => 10 );

   $innerloop = new WP_Query( $innerargs );
   while ( $innerloop ->have_posts() ) : $innerloop ->the_post();
      echo 'paid Comment';
   endwhile;

endwhile; 
?>
```

untested though. 
hopefully this will help,

Comment: Thanks Marty but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, this echos out "paid Comment" a number of times more than it logically should. Never the less thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'ait-dir-item',
                       'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'location',
                                'value' => 'annapolis'
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key' => 'item_tags',
                                'value' => 'non-marine'
                            )
                        ),
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                       'posts_per_page' => 300 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            the_title('<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>');
            echo '<div class="entry-content">';
            the_content();
            echo '</div>';
        endwhile;?>
```

you can try this one